# Enhancing PDF (handwritten text)

Tags: applications, pdf, editing

I scanned many handwritten sheets (written by using a pencil and scanned by using a PC software), and I'm wondering if there is a way to enhance the handwritten text quality: the text is grey and there is some colored figures.

My goal is to make the text darker.

Comment: Hello. Why don't you try enhancement before committing scan into a pdf? Enhancing images are easier than doing that to a pdf.

Comment: Hi, take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Hello @AndrewT. could you tell me if the edit is ok please?

Comment: Hi @Firelord that process requires more time; in a photocopy shop the scanning is done by using an automatic machine.